# Linq Slowness on Single Call

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

Background: my game is using a component system. I have an `Entity` class which has a list of `IComponent` instances in a `List<IComponent>`. My current implementation of `Entity.GetComponent<T>()` is:

`return (T)this.components.Single(c => c is T);`

After adding collision detection, I noticed my game dropped to 1FPS. Profiling revealed the culprit to be this very call (which is called 3000+ times per frame).

3000x aside, I noticed that calling this 300k times takes about 2 seconds. I optimized it to a simple iterative loop:

```
foreach (IComponent c in this.components) { 
  if (c is T) {
    return (T)c; 
  }
}

return default(T);
```

This code now runs in about 0.4s, which is an order of magnitude better.

I thought `Single` would be much more efficient than a single foreach loop. What's going on here?

Comment: You can replace Single with FirstOrDefault which will simply return the first occurrence, should be as fast as your iterative loop

Comment: If you prefer to abstract away the casting, you can use `OfType<T>()` like this: `return this.components.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Thanks Martheen and @RiskyMartin, I will incorporate your suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The doc for `Single` says:

> Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if
>   there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

On the other hand `First`:

> The first element in the sequence that passes the test in the
>   specified predicate function.

So, with `Single` you traverse the whole sequence without `short circuiting`, which is what the `foreach` loop above does. So, use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Single`.

Comment: Semantically, `Single` throws an exception if more than one object meeting that criterion exists. How do I keep that behaviour if I'm using `First`

Comment: You cannot do that without traversing the whole list. If you need to know about dupes, you have to use Single, or manage your own data structure that indexes how many of each type exist in memory.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

Single iterates through the entire collection and makes sure only one item is found. So your best performance is always O(N)

Your iterative search is also subject to O(N) performance, but that is a worst case scenario.

Source: 
[List<T>.Single Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb919331%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that i'm not exactly sure that .Single is an iterative search, it could also go through the collection multiple times.